# Out-File -Encoding problems using PowerShell replace command

Tags: powershell, encoding, gradlew

I am modifying dummy file `a.gradle` which in on my desktop and then trying to replace it with actual Github project's gradle file under git directory on my local machine using below PowerShell command

```
Get-Content "a.gradle" -replace 'foo', 'bar'| Out-File "b.gradle"
```

But When I tried to run gradlw test command it is throwing an error:

> unexpected char: 0x0 @ line 1, column 4. `??a p p l y   p l u g i n :   ' j a v a '`

I tried appending "encoding "UTF8" after `Out-File` command but it is not working.

Comment: `Out-File` / `>`, as of PSv5.1, create "Unicode" (UTF16-LE) files by default, where each character is represented by (typically) 2 bytes. `-Encoding UTF8` produces UTF-8, but invariably prepends a BOM to the output file. Most Unix-heritage utilities can't handle either, and expect UTF-8 _without a BOM_. The question linked to by @JamesQMurphy has answers with solutions.

Comment: Additional to the above comments keep in mind that powershell cmdlets that write to a file have the tendency to add lines when not necessary. Just use the internal dotnet sdk form the `System.IO.File` class or use the `-NoNewLine` parameter when available.